App se cierra al conectar a firebase error
Al ejecutar una app desarrollada en android studio se cierra. Presenta el siguiente error.

java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
ComponentInfo{com.example.quick/ com.example.quick.MenuActivity}:
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #15 in
com.example.quick:layout/ activity_menu: Binary XML file line #19 in
com.example.quick:layout/content_menu: Error inflating class fragment
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(A
ctivityThread.java:3909).

Creo que el error es este:

Error running 'MenuActivity' The activity must be exported or contain
an intent-filter.

No se como solucionarlo. Gracias

Prueba agregar exported="true" en el manifest a MenuActivity

lo he probado y ahora  me presenta este error: AAPT: error: unexpected element  found in 

Ponlo en la pregunta

Actualmente, a todas las activities o servicios que tengan definido un intent-filter en tu AndroidManifest.xml como este ejemplo:
<activity android:name=".MenuActivity">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
    

debes agregar el atributo android:exported, como este ejemplo:
<activity android:name=".MenuActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        

Puedes revisar más sobre este cambio en:
Cambios en el comportamiento: apps orientadas a Android 12
específicamente en Exportación de componentes más segura:

lo he probado y ahora  me presenta este error: AAPT: error: unexpected element  found in 

Me parece que hay algún error en los cierres de elementos ">", si quierea actualiza tu pregunta agregando tu AndroidManifest.xml

Muchas gracias. He abierto una nueva pregunta. con el codigo que he utilizado.

Muchas gracias. He abierto una nueva pregunta. con el codigo que he utilizado. Dejo el enlace: https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/625582/387055

@Eslacce ya te respondí ahí Eslacce
