Error Android Studio_Firebase: App se cierra al conectar
Al ejecutar la app desarrollada en android studio, esta secierra. Presenta el siguiente error: AAPT: error: unexpected element  found in 
Aun no identifico el  error. El codigo que he utilizado es este:
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Quick"
        tools:targetApi="31">
        <activity
            android:name=".MenuActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_menu"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.Quick.NoActionBar" />
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">

        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>


Únicamente los componentes que usan intent-filter deben usar el atributo android_exported, por ejemplo esta Activity no usa intent-filter, por lo tanto no debería tener android:exported="true"
<activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:exported="true">

    </activity>

Debería ser simplemente:
<activity
        android:name=".MainActivity">

    </activity>


Además, te falta el cierre (</activity> ) de la Activity launcher
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Quick"
        tools:targetApi="31">
        <activity
            android:name=".MenuActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_menu"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.Quick.NoActionBar" />
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        </activity>  <=== *Falta este cierre de activity.

        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">    
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>


Si, eso había intentado, pero el error persiste y el programa me señala las líneas de inicio y final del ". Además, al borrar el " android:exported" o modificarlo a false, me muestra la cruz roja sobre el símbolo de android, esto en la parte superior.

@Eslacce revisa mi actualización

@Eslacce recuerda que si esta respuesta ayuda a resolver el problema planteado en la pregunta, marcar como solución, revisar [tour], saludos.
